# When i add to the list in my dictionary, it doesn't actually add to the list? python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pickle

So, I made a dictionary, called groupA, that i want to hold names and multiple scores. The scores come from a variable called count, which is dependent on a quiz from another part of my code. My code adds multiple values to one key, but i want them all in one list, which isn't happening for whatever reason. This is my code:

```
     name = input("What is your name? ")
    while name.isdigit():
        print ("That's not a name.")
        name = input("What is your name? ")
    group = input("Which group are you in; A, B or C: ")
    if group == "A":
         if name in groupA:
             groupA = pickle.load(open("groupA.p", "rb"))
             score = [count] 
             groupA[name].append(score)
             numberofvalues = len(score)
             if numberofvalues > 3:
                 print("Deleting oldest score.")
                 score.pop(1)
                 print(score)
             pickle.dump(groupA, open("groupA.p", "wb"))
         else:
            score = [count] 
            groupA[name] = [score]
            pickle.dump(groupA, open("groupA.p", "wb"))
```

i want this part of the code to either add to the values in the list, and if there are more than three values in the list, delete the first, then if there isn't an entry for the dictionary with that name; create an entry, but it's not doing this. can someone please help? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are currently doing is equivalent to:

```
groupA[name].append([count])  # this appends a list to the list
```

Do it this way

```
groupA[name].append(count)  # count must be single value
```

And in the else part

```
groupA[name] = [count]  # creating new single-element list
```

Also, `len(scores)` will always be 1. Replace it with this:

```
numberofvalues = len(groupA[name])
```

Comment: the output now looks like this: {'Georgia': [[10, 9, 5], 5]}     how should i fix this?

Comment: Is `count` always a single value? Try clearing your pickled files and start from scratch.

Comment: I still get a weird output {'Georgia': [[6], 6]} and yes, it is always a single value

Comment: Are you sure you are doing `.append(count)` and `groupA[name] = [count]`? Can you post your modified code?

Comment: ahhh, i forgot to add groupA[name] = count, sorry for the trouble, but thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem. If your question is answered by any post (on any stackexchange sites), you should mark it is accepted. (tick mark to left)